# nuxt app served through reverse proxy producing ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error in browser

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app running in a conda env on a Centos 8 virtual machine. It is set to serve on a URL via reverse proxy using nginx. The page loads fine but continuously produces **ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING** error in browser while open, while making a request like this: **[url]/_loading/sse**. Does anybody have an idea what may be going on?

This should be a reproducible workflow. Install a basic nuxt app in a newly created conda environment:

```
conda install nodejs
npm init nuxt-app nuxt-test
```

Mostly chose defaults for the options offered during npm init, but perhaps relevant are

```
UI framework: Bootstrap Vue
Server: Node.js hosting
```

The default nuxt app created this way will run on port 3000. Modify /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to serve this:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

Run the nuxt app

```
npm run dev
```

Access this 2 ways: first by port forwarding - this does not produce the above mentioned error; second by accessing the URL defined in nginx - wait 1 minute and the error starts being produced (both in Chrome and Edge browsers). I have also tried this on my PC in a conda environment without the nginx (running directly on localhost:3000), and it does not produce the errors. I have also tried this with apache/httpd as reverse proxy instead of nginx with the same result, so I don't believe it is an nginx issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this problem does not occur if I follow the production deployment option, rather than development:

```
npm run build
npm run start
```

I don't understand why "npm run dev" creates this issue, but at least I found a workaround. Hopefully it will help someone, as I had been banging my head against this for two days.